# Batch file not copying 1 file but copies another

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

I have a batch file and pretty much all it does is copy call sqlcmd, which runs fine, and copy the file to a usb drive.

This is the line I am having problems with:

```
copy E:\DatabaseBackup\First.bak G:\DatabaseBackup\.
copy E:\DatabaseBackup\Second.bak G:\DatabaseBackup\.
```

The first line is where it breaks. I get this message:

The parameter is incorrect.
        0 file(s) copied.

The second line works fine. I've tried altering the line buy not using a . and even using robocopy, even tried swaping the order they copy, but no luck.

It is due to the size of the bak file? Here are the sizes:

```
03/02/2016  02:11 PM    55,650,206,208 First.bak
03/02/2016  02:13 PM     2,174,265,856 Second.bak
```

I verified the directory exists,  even though the 2nd copy works fine.

Any suggestions?

**IN RESPONSE TO Varon**

This is the properties of the usb drive:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The maximum possible size for a file on a FAT32 volume is 4 GB minus 1 byte or 4,294,967,295 (2^32 − 1) bytes.

Check the target filesystem `G:` in this case

Source: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32

Comment: Thank you for your response! If I understand you correctly, the drive is formatted to NTFS. See the above image.

Comment: @ErocM: that changes things a lot

Comment: I had the wrong drive and it was FAT32. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, nice! Anyway, for other readers: There was only one option left: The File-Permissions of NTFS of the source drive. You can check them in console for a special file with ICACLS <file>. Maybe you are not allowed read it.